How to Modify XGBoost to Apply a Custom Factor to Predicted Values Exceeding a Threshold?
I am using XGBoost to build a predictive model. My goal is to modify the standard XGBoost behavior such that if the predicted time exceeds a certain threshold, the prediction is multiplied by a factor. This factor and threshold should be hyperparameters that can be optimized.
Here is the current implementation and my attempt to modify the fit method of XGBoostRegressor to achieve this. However, I am unsure if my approach is correct and how to properly integrate this into the fit method. Could someone guide me on the best way to implement this?
import warnings
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score, train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from xgboost import DMatrix

# Custom XGBoost Regressor with modified fit method
class CustomXGBRegressor(xgb.XGBRegressor):
    def __init__(self, factor=1.0, threshold=400, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.factor = factor
        self.threshold = threshold

    def fit(self, X, y, **kwargs):
        super().fit(X, y, **kwargs)
        preds = self.predict(X)
        modified_preds = np.where(preds > self.threshold, preds * self.factor, preds)
        self._Booster.set_attr(preds=modified_preds.tolist())

# Load data
data = pd.read_csv('input_file.csv')
target_column = 'duration'

X = data.drop(columns=[target_column])
y = data[target_column]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42,  shuffle=True)
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

model = CustomXGBRegressor(
    monotone_constraints='()',
    base_score=0.5,
    booster="gbtree",
    colsample_bylevel=1,
    colsample_bynode=1,
    colsample_bytree=1,
    enable_categorical=False,
    gamma=0,
    gpu_id=-1,
    importance_type=None,
    interaction_constraints='',
    max_delta_step=0,
    max_depth=10,
    n_estimators=106,
    learning_rate=0.05,
    subsample=1,
    reg_alpha=1.507,
    reg_lambda=0.011,
    min_child_weight=2,
    n_jobs=8,
    num_parallel_tree=1,
    predictor='auto',
    random_state=0,
    scale_pos_weight=1,
    tree_method='exact',
    validate_parameters=1,
    verbosity=None,
    objective='reg:squarederror',
    factor=1.5,
    threshold=400
)

warnings.simplefilter('ignore')

kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=7, shuffle=True)
results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold)

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)],
          eval_metric='mape')

# Plotting the results
 y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'real': y_test, 'pred': y_pred})
df1 = df1.sort_values('real').reset_index(drop=True)
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))
plt.plot(df1.index, df1['real'], label='Real', linestyle='-', marker='o', markersize=1.5)
plt.plot(df1.index, df1['pred'], label='Predicted', linestyle='', marker='o',    markersize=1.5)
plt.xlabel('Index', fontsize=33)
plt.ylabel('Duration [s]', fontsize=33)
plt.legend(fontsize=30)
plt.xticks(fontsize=25)
plt.yticks(fontsize=25)
plt.show()

Questions:
Is my approach to modifying the fit method correct?
How can I ensure that the modified predictions are properly stored and used during evaluation?
Are there any best practices or alternative approaches for implementing such custom modifications in XGBoost?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
